# bash: processing (recursively) through all files in a directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I want to write a bash script that (recursively) processes all files of a certain type.

I know I can get the matching file list by using find thusly:

find . -name "*.ext"

I want to use this in a script:

1. recursively obatin list of files with a given extension
2. obtain the full file pathname
3. pass the full pathname to another script
4. Check the return code from the script. If non zero, log the name of the file that could not be processed.

My first attempt looks (pseudocode) like this:

```
ROOT_DIR = ~/work/projects
cd $ROOT_DIR
for f in `find . -name "*.ext"`
do
    #need to lop off leading './' from filename, but I havent worked out how to use
    #cut yet
    newname = `echo $f | cut -c 3
    filename = "$ROOT_DIR/$newname"

    retcode = ./some_other_script $filename

    if $retcode ne 0
       logError("Failed to process file: $filename")
done
```

This is my first attempt at writing a bash script, so the snippet above is not likely to run. Hopefully though, the logic of what I'm trying to do is clear enough, and someone can show how to join the dots and convert the pseudocode above into a working script.

I am running on Ubuntu

Comment: If you use 'find $ROOT_DIR -name "*.exe"' you won't need to fiddle with the leading './'.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.ext' \( -exec ./some_other_script "$PWD"/{} \; -o -print \)
```

Comment: +1 Good solution, I didn't know you could use -o this way. The only problem is that sometimes (not here) you need to call a function instead of an external executable.

Comment: Hmm quite cryptic this .... (reminds me of Perl!). I dont understand this. How is the filename being passed to the other script, and how do I know if the script returned non zero, so I know to do something?

Comment: @skyeagle: The `{}` in the `-exec` predicate indicates where to inject the current match. The `-exec` predicate itself tests the result code of the command, yielding true if 0, false otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Using `| while read` to iterate over file names is fine as long as there are no files with carrier return to be processed:

```
find . -name '*.ext' | while IFS=$'\n' read -r FILE; do
  process "$(readlink -f "$FILE")" || echo "error processing: $FILE"
done
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it's officially discouraged at all. It's much better than `for f in $(find)`. There can be issues if there are spaces, tabs or newlines in filenames. It can be improved like this: `while IFS=$'\n' read -r FILE`

Comment: @Dennis, I cannot find the page right now (may be not that official), but it discouraged using "while | read" because carrier returns are valid characters for files (fortunately nobody uses them). Added your suggestion.

Comment: Such assumptions are always problematic. Even if "normal" users often avoid newlines in file names, it doesn't mean nobody does it—and an attacker will certainly do it. Any program should try hard to accept all allowed file names; fortunately that is quite easy in every real programming language—another reason to avoid shell scripts.

Comment: @Philipp: Well, this is a more general discussion. I wouldn't call shell languages "non-real programming languages", but indeed they have their drawbacks and historical luggage. However, IMHO they deserve high respect for devising one of the most powerful programming concepts ever: piping.

Comment: Perhaps you were thinking of [this page](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html). It's a good discussion of the challenges presented by filenames.

Comment: @tokland: I agree that shell languages are useful, but they are also much overrated, as this question once more shows. The biggest hurdle of Bash and friends is that "function" (i.e., programs) work solely on strings, and you have to devise custom serialization schemes to implement more complex data structures. The equivalent of `find` in other languages can just return an array or an iterator. More modern shells like PowerShell have acknowledged this deficit and allow passing and returning arbitrary objects.

Comment: @dennis: no, it wasn't that page, but this is an impressive essay on the matter indeed! I liked this statement: "Adding small limits to filenames makes it much easier to create completely-correct programs". I can live with that. Anyway, @philip surely has a point here: if such a "simple" issue became so complicated, something must have gone wrong in its inception. @philip: "you have to devise custom serialization schemes to implement more complex data structures". This contraint has traditionally seen is a strength: allowing only strings (the universal interface) was a key design idea.